# Using vba to create an auto filter for data

Tags: excel, vba

I have worked out the code to apply a filter based on a dynamic criteria, but the trouble I am having is with removing the drop down arrows from the possible fields as I do not want the user to be able to change any of them. My second question is how to remove the filter criteria upon click of a command button in order to reset the data fields for the next user. I'd like to note that the `Field:=1,_` Line does remove the dropdown arrow, but only for the first field. My code is posted below, any help is appreciated.

```
Sub test()
Worksheets("Tracker").Range("A1:L1").AutoFilter _
 Field:=1, _
 Criteria1:=Sheets("Start").Range("J2"), _
 VisibleDropDown:=False



'This is supposed to remove the dropdown arrow from the remaining feilds in the sheet, but will not
With Range("A1:L1")
.AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=3, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=7, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=8, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=9, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=10, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=11, VisibleDropDown:=False
.AutoFilter Field:=12, VisibleDropDown:=False

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Advanced Filter your criteria can be on a different worksheet. Your result will appear to the end users just like a regular worksheet with no indication that it was filtered.

With Advanced Filter your criteria can be dynamic and hidden from the user.

Just record a macro to to do the Advanced Filter, assign it to a button and away you go. There is a great website out there on Advanced Filter.

The key is that the data table, the Criteria and your Copy To range can all be on separate sheets.

Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate the help! I now have a great start from using the recorded macro. I just need to make some minor adjustments, but overall it looks good. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Advanced Filter is pretty useful, but not a lot of people know about it.

Comment: I may have spoke to soon... the recorded macro worked well, but now I need to fit it to my specific data set. This is my code and for whatever reason it will activate the correct sheet, but the filter will not initiate at all. Can you help?                                                                               `Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
Sheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1:L27").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets(1).Range("A11:L12"), Unique:=False
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub`

Comment: From a quick look, you don't have a statement for the copy to range like

Comment: From a quick look, you don't have a statement for the copy to range like CopyToRange:=Range(A6:Z6). I've never tried an advanced filter without a copy to range, so it might work. Are you getting an error of some sort?  Are you working all in the same workbook? or across multiple workbooks?

Comment: I generally start my Advanced filter code like this: Range ("A9".Select (select the top left cell in my copy to range), Then Range ("Datasource").advancedfilter Action: xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range(filtercrit), CopyToRange: =Range (A9:Z9), Unique:=False. I use defined names for my data source, my criteria and my copytorange to make things clearer

Comment: Tim- Thank you so much, your code has saved me a lot of time struggling with this filter problem. My last question is for some reason the criteria range works when I initiate a filter through the data tab, but when I use the same range for the vba code it does not get filtered. Any thoughts?